# Spring application fails to start with ActiveJDBC instrumented classes

Tags: java, spring, maven, activejdbc

I am using Java 8, ActiveJDBC 1.4.13 and Spring Boot 2.0.0.RC1 with Spring 5.

On application startup I am getting this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: FooActiveModel.class;
```

This problem appeared when I upgraded from Spring Boot 2.0.0.M7 to 2.0.0.RC1.

I have found a few references to this error but no mention of ActiveJDBC. In my case classes extended from the `activejdbc.Model` class (instrumented classes) are causing the problem.

As per answers and suggestions in these...

- [SPRING4: Failed to read candidate component class CouchbaseConfig.class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32941815/1014789)
- [Server fails to start, Spring throws BeanDefinitionParsingException](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21336062/1014789)
- [BeanDefinitionStoreException Failed to read candidate component class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22771826/1014789)
- [ArrayOutOfBoundsException on Bean creation while using Java 8 constructs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30729125/1014789)

I have...

- made sure I'm using Java 8
- searched for conflicting dependencies
- cleaned and rebuilt my project
- deleted local maven repo that "might" have been corrupted
- re-imported all the dependencies
- upgraded all dependencies to their latest version

These options did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally managed to solve this problem by excluding the problematic classes(the ones extended from `activejdbc.Model` that were being instrumented) from the spring component scan.

To make sure that this was actually the reason for the error, I even reverted to my original `pom.xml` with all my previous dependency versions, re-imported everything, cleaned, rebuilt and sure enough I'm no longer having this issue.

This was an extremely frustrating and time consuming problem, hope it helps somebody.